# What is the Rails way of handling edits made to a resource's ActiveStorage attachment(s)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attachment, conventions, rails-activestorage

I'm trying out ActiveStorage for the first time and wondering what the convention is for controller code used to purge some or all of a resource's attached files?

Two solutions I can see, and hate:

1. A designated controller just for managing attachments (which would omit any kind of resource specific callbacks)
2. In each resource controller add some kind of logic to the `destroy` methods

What is the Rails way of handling edits made to a resource's ActiveStorage attachment(s)?

Answer (score 1):

I’d choose the first solution you considered:

> A designated controller just for managing attachments (which would omit any kind of resource specific callbacks

This is roughly what we do in Basecamp. Here’s a demo:

```
# app/models/event.rb
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many_attached :highlights
end
```

```
# app/controllers/events/highlights_controller.rb
class Events::HighlightsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_event, :set_highlight

  def destroy
    @highlight.purge_later
    redirect_to @event
  end

  private
    def set_event
      @event = Current.user.events.find(params[:event_id])
    end

    def set_highlight
      @highlight = @event.highlights.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :events do
    resources :highlights, controller: "events/highlights"
  end
end
```

```
<%# app/views/events/show.html.erb %>
<% @event.highlights.each do |highlight| %>
  <%= link_to image_tag(highlight.representation(resize: "200x200>")), highlight %><br>
  <%= link_to "Delete this highlight", event_highlight_path(@event, highlight), method: :delete %>
<% end %>
```